# Turning jquery into usable string in R

Tags: jquery, r, mixpanel

I am trying to convert the following jquery code into a string that I can pass into a function in R:

```
function main() {
  return join(
    Events({
    from_date: '2016-09-01',
    to_date:   '2016-12-01',
    event_selectors: [{selector: 'event["event.name"]=="Page 
Viewed"'}]
   }),
  People({
     user_selectors: [{selector: 'user["Is Test"]==false'}]
   }),   
  {type:'left'})
}
```

Since the query includes both single and double quotes, I can't simply wrap it in whichever one isn't present.

I have tried simply wrapping it into double quotes and then using escape characters for the double quotes inside the query, as shown below:

```
  "function main() {
     return join(
      Events({
        from_date: '2016-09-01',
        to_date:   '2016-12-01',
        event_selectors: [{selector: 'event[\"event.name\"]==\"Page 
Viewed\"'}]
      }),
      People({
        user_selectors: [{selector: 'user[\"Is Test\"]==false'}]
      }),   
      {type:'left'})
  }"
```

But the problem is that when I run that string in R the escape characters actually show up, and I need to pass the original, untainted query into the 'mixpanelJQLQuery()' function in the 'RMixpanel' library.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign your function to a variable and then just simply concat it with an empty string, doing it like:

```
var myFunction = function main() { /* your code here */ }
var stringifiedFunction = '' + myFunction;
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7t13w2ju/) here.

Hope it helps. :)